# Android4.0 Sample SampleSyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am study the samples of the new Android Version IceCream to try new features.
Here I run the sample which name is SampleSyncAdapter,but I can't connect to the server successfully, the server url is: http://samplesyncadapter2.appspot.com/, I also tried it with my browser, and get failed either, are there anyone who have tried this sample successfully?

Comment: Do other App Engine sites work for you, such as http://jumpnote.appspot.com/? If not, you may want to check your proxy settings or otherwise check with your ISP.

Comment: Thanks, I tried  jumpnote.appspot.com by my browser but still can't access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server does work for me; if for some reason you're unable to reach the server (or other App Engine apps), an alternative is to [download the App Engine SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) and run a local server. The server-side source code for `SampleSyncAdapter` is packaged with the rest of the sample code in the `samplesyncadapter_server/` directory.

Comment: Thanks very much, I can run server sample successfuly, all the functions can run now.